# Binary Search Ruby

Tags: ruby, binary-search-tree

I am trying to write a simple code for simulating binary search, let's supposed the array is sorted already.  x is the array, y is the number I want to find. I want to know how many steps it take to find the y(counter is the result I want). what's wrong with my code?

thanks so much!

```
x = ["2,", "5", "7", "10", "20", "30", "50", "90", "101", "120"]
y = 101
mid = (x.count.to_f/2).ceil
z = x[mid].to_i
counter = 0

while y != z
  counter += 1
  if y < z
    mid = (mid/2).ceil
  else
    mid = mid + (mid/2).ceil
  end
end

print(counter)
```

Comment: Maybe you can tell us what's wrong. Do you get any errors?

Comment: This array is not sorted.

Comment: @holger just, nothing, just no result showing, it looks like was in the loop forever

Comment: As @SergioTulentsev said, your array" is not sorted: `["2,", "5", "7", "10", "20", "30", "50", "90", "101", "120"].sort
# => ["10", "101", "120", "2,", "20", "30", "5", "50", "7", "90"]`. In addition, even when it is, you might want to check the value `"2,"`. You also might want to consider working with an array of integers before moving to an array of strings as the sort order is more obvious, which will make it easier for you to debug.

Comment: On top of everything, your algorithms is implemented plain wrong, as `z` is assigned to only before the loop, so it never changes.

Answer (score 0):

This won't work because your array contains string. String are compared using alphabetical order.

```
"5" > "10"
=> true
```

Thus, your array is not sorted. But, you could add leading zeros, so that string comparison works like you expect:

```
a.map{|e| e.rjust(4, "0") }

"0005" < "0010"
=>true
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks everyone for your input, I made it work :

```
x = [2, 5, 7, 10, 20, 30, 50, 90, 101, 120]
puts "Which character you want to find?"
y = gets.chomp.to_i
first = 0
last = x.count - 1
mid = (x[first..last].count.to_f/2).ceil
z = x[mid-1].to_i
counter = 1

while y != z
  counter += 1
  if y < z
    last = mid
    mid = mid - (x[first..last].count/2).ceil
    z = x[mid]
  else
    first = mid
    mid = mid + (x[first..last].count.to_f/2).ceil
    z = x[mid-1]
  end
end

puts "the answer is #{counter}."
```